# $sanitize Custom Whitelist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, sanitization

The `$sanitize` service [tells me that](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize)

> All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to
>   properly escaped html string.

I want to only display an even smaller subset of HTML (viz `em`,`p`,`a`, and `strong`). Is there a way to easily modify the `$service` whitelist without having to modify the core JavaScript?

Comment: Copy the source of the directive and make your own from it ;)

Comment: I could (and sadly I've had to do it with angular-resource), but I want to avoid diverging from the base files as much as possible.

Comment: Did you end up with a solution to this? or did you create your own?

Comment: @user3319803 I ended up forking Angular's and modifying it to our needs: https://github.com/BYU-ODH/hummedia-client/blob/master/app/js/custom-sanitize.js though I hadn't checked jdforsythe's solution as this was already done by the time that solution was offered, so theirs might be a better route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use $delegate (as jdforsythe mentioned) **and** some other library. I personally use [sanitizeHtml](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) in my project because it allows me to choose which tags to allow. The setup:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .config(['$provide', ($provide) => {
        $provide.decorator('$sanitize', ['$delegate', ($delegate) => {
            return function(text, target) {
                const preSanitizedText = sanitizeHtml(text, {
                    allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a']
                });
                return $delegate(preSanitizedText, target);
            };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can decorate the $sanitize service to avoid changing the source files. Here's an example that just logs what happens inside $sanitize. You can do what you need to filter unwanted elements.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator("$sanitize", function($delegate, $log){
        return function(text, target){

            var result = $delegate(text, target);
            $log.info("$sanitize input: " + text);
            $log.info("$sanitize output: " + result);

            return result;
        };
    });
});
```

Note that inside of the decorator, $delegate refers to the $santize. You'll filter what you want out of the input before calling $delegate(text, target) then return the result.